# Find density function of Y given X

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$$f(x)=
 \begin{cases}
  e^{-x}, & \text{if } x\geq0;\\
  0, & \text{if }x<1.
 \end{cases}
$$
and,
$$Y=
 \begin{cases}
  X, & \text{if } X\leq1;\\
  \dfrac{1}{X}, & \text{if }X>1.
 \end{cases}
$$ 
Find the probability density function of Y.
The solution said to use Total Probability to get

$G(Y)=P(Y\le y)=P(Y\le y\vert X\le1)P(X\le1)+P(Y\le y\vert X\gt1)P(X\gt 1) $.
From which I get,
$ P(Y\le y\vert X\le1)(1-e^{-1})+P(Y\le y\vert X\gt1)(e^{-1})$ and I am unable to continue any further. Your guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
P(Y\leq y\mid X\leq 1)=P(X\leq y\mid X\leq 1)=\begin{cases}1, & y\geq 1\\
\frac{P(X\leq y,\, X\leq 1)}{P(X\leq 1)}=\frac{P(X\,\leq \,y)}{P(X\,\leq\, 1)}, &  0<y< 1\\
0, & y\leq 0\end{cases}
$$
$$
P(Y\leq y\mid X > 1)=P\left(\frac1X\leq y\mid X> 1\right)=\begin{cases}1, &  y\geq 1\\
\frac{P(X\geq y^{-1},\,X> 1)}{P(X> 1)}=\frac{P(X\,\geq \,y^{-1})}{P(X\,> 1)}, &  0<y< 1\\
0, & y\leq 0\end{cases}
$$
Calculate the probabilities and substitute it to expression for $G(y)$.

Comment: Hi, why is $P(X\le 0\vert X\le 1) = 0 $. We know that X is less than or equal to 1, how can we say for certain that it is never less than or equal to zero

Comment: Since unconditional probability $P(X\leq 0)=0$ is  equal to zero for exponential distribution.